# How to db:migrate after db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a production db, that I prepare with

```
rake db:create db:schema:load db:seed
```

I also include migrations, when delivering my product, so that existing installations can be updated.

After schema:load only the version of the latest migration is stored in schema_migrations, so when I run db:migrate, the migrator tries to run all other migrations that are not yet in schema_migrations.

Is there a good way, to deal with this, that does not require me, to collapse migrations (because that is unfortunately out of the question - just like db:migrate as the preparation step)?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't db:schema:load, pass migrations instead:

```
rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

Please keep in mind that in big/long projects passing migrations is a hard way. You should tru to keep your seeds.rb updated and use you way. Old migrations tends to fail because of incompatible model changes (in respect to old migrations) as the project evolutes.

Comment: You're right, it's hard to keep old migrations working. With the age and size of this project unfortunately there's no way we get to spend the time necessary to get those to work again. That's why in the last sentence I mentioned, that db:migrate is no option.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you right. Actually, in my projects db:reset didn't cause old migrations to pass again. Well, I once had a very old project, evoluting since rails 2.*, where I just deleted all old migrations, and had no problems with it. Git will keep track just in case ;)